# Angular 14, как подгружать произвольный файл с бэка?

Tags: angular, frontend

Всем привет! При сборке проекта Angular получается несколько файлов:

[image: файлы]

Они же подгружаются в браузер и там работают. Мне надо сделать так чтобы подгружался ещё один файл (JSON или другой текстовый формат) и он был бы доступен из TS-кода.

Для чего это надо: чтобы бэкенд при инициализации приложения записывал туда данные, которые потом используются на фронте. Эти данные всегда новые при каждом старте бэка.

Что я пробовал: в папку assets клал JSON, в коде импортировал и выводил в консоль. Что получилось: Ангуляр захардкодил данные этого JSON в файл main....js, т.е. он "соптимизировал" переменную в константу.

Вопрос: как можно втянуть в браузер дополнительный файл?

Comment: Что мешает забирать данные с помощью HttpClient?

Comment: Мешает то что фронт не знает IP-адреса бэка (сеть внутренняя, DNS нет). Именно адрес для настройки HTTP-клиента я и хочу передавать при загрузке фронта в браузер.

Comment: Ну, например, собирайте на бэке тот же index.html с подключенными файлами, либо заведите заведите статический файл, который get ом забирать будете с нужными адресами и встраивайте самостоятельно. Может как вариант подойдут куки.

Comment: Я уже пробовал по-всякому. Смысл в том что мне надо подтягивать внешний по отношению к Ангуляр-проекту файл, а он это не делает из соображений безопасности. Что логично т.к. можно где-то что-то подменить и он вытянет непонятно что. В общем, я (пока) отказался эмбедить фронт как статику в бэк и теперь за фронт у меня будет отвечать NGINX. А конфиг-файл я буду подселять внутрь Ангуляр-проекта (assets или отдельная папка). Это по-любому правильнее, но хотелось сделать всё в одном JAR-файле.